# spanner ResultSet.next() does pagination internally?how it will return billions of rows?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm using java spanner read api. In the read call is the table has billions of data then spanner ResultSet.next() does pagination internally?

How it will return billions of rows?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a streaming api, check out https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/SpannerImpl.java#L2316 for implementation.